# Rails 4 Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

which gem is best for authentication in Rails 4?? I try to use devise but I got problem with it.

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in `attr_accessible': `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one. (RuntimeError)
    from /home/leapfrog/projects/kathloc/app/models/user.rb:8:in `<class:User>'
    from /home/leapfrog/projects/kathloc/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `block in load_file'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `load_file'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:534:in `get'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:565:in `constantize'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise.rb:261:in `get'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise.rb:291:in `new'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise.rb:291:in `add_mapping'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:193:in `block in devise_for'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:192:in `each'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:192:in `devise_for'
    from /home/leapfrog/projects/kathloc/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:320:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:320:in `eval_block'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:298:in `draw'
    from /home/leapfrog/projects/kathloc/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `initialize!'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/leapfrog/projects/kathloc/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/application.rb:187:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm really annoyed. Every new rails release has some incompatibities with some gems, I pass my time in resolving these incompatibilities not developing.

Comment: Tell me about it. It struck me that Rails is like a dictatorship, with people that have been developing for years the only ones who get a say in how it moves forwards. What about the new guys? Rails 2.0 is a LOT easier to understand than Rails 4.0; it's getting madly esoteric. And you need to get newbies on board if an open source project is going to grow.  Abstracting this functionality out into the controller is just stupid. It should be with the model. But you can't say this in an irc. People treat rails like a damn religion. It was a stupid idea to do this and they should change it back.

Answer (score 26):

It is because in **rails-4**, `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity` has been taken out of ActiveModel. But devise uses **attr_accessible**, hence to use that, just add the following gem in ur **Gemfile** and try to load once again.

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

**EDIT:**

Now devise is supporting for rails-4. Include this in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'
```

Comment: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity was removed for good reason; it's fundamentally flawed, and has been replaced by [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). So it's probably best not to recommend blindly bringing it back with the [protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) gem. No doubt Devise will (or has already) become compatible with Rails 4 without MassAssignmentSecurity.

Comment: Devise 3.0.0rc supports Rails 4.

Comment: Yes, now it is supporting for rails-4, but when i gave the answer to the above post, the development for enhancement was in progress.

Comment: Thanks. Adding gem 'protected_attributes' to my Gemfile let me use attr_accessible on rails4/ruby1.9.3.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit**: there is now a Devise version supporting Rails 4: [Devise 3.0.0.rc](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions/3.0.0.rc)

**Previous answer**:
What I did on my end to make it work just fine is...

1. In Gemfile:

   `gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'`
2. In generated model, remove the `attr_accessible` stuff.
3. Enable Strong Parameters for Devise instead of attr_accessible. To do so, create a new initiliazer with that content:

   ```
   DeviseController.class_eval do
     def resource_params
       unless params[resource_name].blank?
         params.require(resource_name).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: You have to clean your previous install of devise before. [uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833161/ruby-how-to-uninstall-devise)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `attr_accessible` with devise in your project, please use accesssibles in following way -

like we have attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, then we can convert them in a private method for security reasons:

```ruby
private

def user_params  
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)

end
```

Comment: Ruby considers # a comment. Looks like you are commenting out  #{file_name}_params. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Vezu please use "#{file_params}" istead of #{file_params}.

Comment: I dont think neither `def #{file_name}_params` nor `def "#{file_name}_params"` is valid in ruby

Comment: @illusionist......I am agree with you, But i am here giving example. Now, I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you need the gem to do. There are lots of options, and Devise is definitely up there at the top. I would suggest Clearance by Thoughtbot(https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance). It's very well tested, and frequently updated. For me, it was very useful when I needed the core authentication functionality and not all of the other stuff that comes with gems like Devise!

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing problem with Devise then try "Authlogic" is also a good gem for authentication.

you can use gem 'authlogic' '~3.2.0' that is the latest version supported Rails 4.0

Ruby toolbox has a list of the most popular ones: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

In the GemFile write gem "devise", "~> 3.0.0.rc".
And follow the instruction provided over here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

I hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the isuue in devise for rails 4.
You can implement it now without any hassle.

just add
gem 'devise' to your Gemfile and do bundle.

Thanks