# Using Rails 4.0 Heroku push attr_accessible error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I've changed all the attr_accessible over to strong parameters in my code, so it works with Rails 4.0. My app runs fine locally, but when I push to Heroku, it's complaining that I have attr_accessible in my code. This is the error I get:

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in `attr_accessible'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/lib/redactor-rails/orm/active_record.rb:20:in `block in extended'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/lib/redactor-rails/orm/active_record.rb:14:in `class_eval'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/lib/redactor-rails/orm/active_record.rb:14:in `extended'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/lib/redactor-rails/orm/active_record.rb:9:in `extend'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/lib/redactor-rails/orm/active_record.rb:9:in `included'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/app/models/redactor_rails/asset.rb:20:in `include'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/app/models/redactor_rails/asset.rb:20:in `<class:Asset>'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/app/models/redactor_rails/asset.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/app/models/redactor_rails/document.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/lib/redactor-rails.rb:31:in `document_model'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/app/controller/redactor_rails/documents_controller.rb:2:in `<class:DocumentsController>'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.5/app/controller/redactor_rails/documents_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_12jc2ej0437ky/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:scratch-cms.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Any ideas on what's going on? Might it be a gem? Might it be devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The problematic gem was redactor. The 0.3.5 version used attr_accessible, and the 0.4 version doesn't. Once I changed the version in my Gemfile, things worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right it is because of devise.It is because in rails-4, ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity has been taken out of ActiveModel. But devise uses attr_accessible, hence to use that, just add the following gem in ur Gemfile and try to load once again.

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

Now devise is supporting for rails-4. try this devise version it will help you

```
gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'
```

**Edit:**
Then I will suggest you to use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520151/rails-4-authentication) it is gives you some idea.

Comment: I've tried devise 3.0.0 non-rc version (the official version has already released), and it still doesn't work. I don't want to use protected_attributes gem because it's like using duct tape, not the best fix. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I solved in this way

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'devise'
gem 'responders',          github: 'plataformatec/responders'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack',            branch: 'rails-4'
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
```

Comment: Know of any other way of fixing this without using protected_attributes? Using that feels like using duct tape on something, not the best way to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

As i see there are 2 problems ->

1.) Include Asset Serving to your Gemfile

```
# static asset serving and logging on Heroku
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

2.) Add whatever attributes you use to your `application_controller.rb`

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
        u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation,
                         :avatar, :firstname, :lastname, :userbio, :country, :gender)
    end
```

Take a look at my Application_Controller -> [here](https://github.com/Theminijohn/vaultX/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb)

Delete your Attr accesible in your models.