# Generate devise install returning errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, installation

I'm new to ROR, I have recently included DEVISE into my Rails project but accidentally I ran a wrong command as follows:

```
rails g devise install
```

After that rails starting showing errors and not working, even the server is not running now.

Here's a screenshot showing the number of errors I'm getting and their details:

[image: errors are shown in the image]

Now even the normal command for installing devise, i.e. devise:install is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Does this command work for you? `rails destroy devise:install`
This should delete your Devise configuration.

Comment: now this is not wokring actually accidently i put wrong command 
rails g devise install,

Comment: That shouldn't just break your whole Rails application. Make sure you have all the required libraries to be able to run Rails on Windows.
Also, make sure you have a runtime available.. If you don't have a lot of changes do a new Rails installation and make sure you branch each change with git for example, so you won't loose any work in the future!

Comment: Again, like I said. **That shouldn't break your Rails application**. Follow this and try and remove all Devise generated files manually. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833161/ruby-how-to-uninstall-devise  -- the most important one should be the Devise config in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Comment: no file with this name as devise was not installed yet, just gem was added,

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is to be honest. As a last resort I'd try a `bundle install` and again, `rails generate devise:install` .. does anything else works for you? Like `rails console` or `rails generate migration TestMyGenerator` ?

Comment: bundle install and update ran , i have removed devise gem as well. but still its showing the above said eror

Comment: Your problem is not Devise then. Something else is wrong with your Rails installation, or maybe even Ruby. I don't know much about running Rails/Ruby on Windows, but I do know it's not easy. I can't help you more, but I can recommend just installing Ruby again and generating a new Rails app.