# Stripe Connect With Parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, parse-platform, stripe-payments

i already have a working stripe connect app but instead of Devise now im having trouble wrapping around how to implement Stripe Connect with Parse.

this is what i already have:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def stripe_connect
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes({
      provider: request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
      uid: request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
      access_code: request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token,
      publishable_key: request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.stripe_publishable_key
    })
      # anything else you need to do in response..
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Stripe") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.stripe_connect_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Also my routes i have:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

I just want to know how i can manipulate this so i can use it with Parse RestApi, thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with Parse REST API?

Comment: i already implemented the log in and log out for Parse Rest API, but once logged in i want the user to connect with stripe and the their stripe keys will be then saved in there account.

Comment: Okay, what library do you use for Parse REST API? Could you show what does that login/logout code look like?

Comment: yeah sure ill gist it. and also im not using a library or gem. im using `gem httparty` to call the api. heres the log in and log out. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2bd7ca84081605239f5d

Comment: Oh, okay. So your question is: what API method could you use to store user data? Because it seems you know *how* to use it.

Comment: well my question is also how i can retrieve the Stripe Keys after Oauth. i first integrated oauth with Devise, but now obviously i dont need devise bevause i have Parse taking its place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove devise, because it's handling user authentication for your site. Parse, on the other hand, in handling your data (basically, saving and restoring it).

In your `#stripe_connect` method you seem to successfully receive data about user, which Stripe gives you after user logs in.

If you want to save that data, learn how to use [Objects API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#objects).

If you want to save information in your own database (instead of Parse), just forget about Parse, your code is fine.

**UPD**. If you are using [omniauth-stripe-connect](https://github.com/isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect), you can get rid of Devise (because you don't need its broad functions, just stripe connect).

Following instructions in the documentation, add the following to `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :stripe_connect, ENV['STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['STRIPE_SECRET']
end
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
```

Then add to your `routes.rb`:

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

Then rename your controller to `SessionsController` and your `stripe_connect` method to `create`. You will have access to the same `request.env['omniauth.auth']` hash.

Comment: why wouldnt i need to get rid of devise? i dont want to use the login/registration anymore. i have Parse as my log in.

Comment: i already have users on Parse, so i want them to be able to log in and then connect with stripe.

Comment: But you want your users to log in via Stripe, or not?

Comment: Yes but just do Stripe Connect, and then ill get there keys, and ill store them in Parse under their user

Comment: Ah, then you need **both** Devise and Parse. Devise is handling Stripe Connect, and then you need to save user's Stripe credentials to Parse. So instead of @user.update_attributes(...) you need to send the same information to Parse.

Comment: Well, you can of course manually implement OAuth. But it's not very simple, and it's much easier to just keep using Devise.

Comment: gotcha, thats what i was wondering. I was thinking i would just manipulate the #stripe_connect and make it so that it saves to current user.

Comment: how do i get rid of the login/registration devise gives

Comment: @user3670235 wait some time, I will update my answer with a general idea of how you do that later today.

Comment: @user3670235 Added to my answer.

Comment: would i get rid of `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }`  in  `routes.rb`

Comment: yes, are you feeling sad for it? don't worry, it will find another programmer to use it after you delete it, and will make home at some other project :)

Comment: also your answer says to delete devise totally?

Comment: yep, that what you asked, and I gave you a solution that doesn't require devise. or do you still need it for something?

Comment: no i dont think i do need it. is there a tutorial where it says how to remove it from an application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833161/ruby-how-to-uninstall-devise – there's a pretty good answer to that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85255/discussion-between-user3670235-and-eugzol).