# I cannot remove devise gem table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem in removing devise gem table in rails, I have remove the migration but my table is still in the schema with the name of User, before I created a devise code mistakenly :

```
  rails d model User
```

And the correct code is :

```
  rails g devise User
```

So how can I remove the devise table in schema

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833161/ruby-how-to-uninstall-devise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833161/ruby-how-to-uninstall-devise Go through to this link

Answer (score 0):

Removing migration files don't drop tables.

In order to remove a table, the most 'straightforward' way to do that is to open your rails console:

```
 rails c
 ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:users)
```